# perl how to add proxy to my script

Tags: perl, proxy

I want add proxy to my script which is interacting with networks(Mainly i want to hide my ip for outgoing request)

How to use it with this script?

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use Mail::VRFY;
use Mail::Verify;
use HTTP::Daemon;
my $emailaddress = $ARGV[0];
my $d = HTTP::Daemon->new( 
LocalHost => "localhost",  # remove this to listen from other machines 
               # (i.e. open-relay... be careful of spammers!)
LocalPort => 8080
) || die;
print "[Proxy URL:", $d->url, "]\n";
#print $email_ck;
my $code = Mail::VRFY::CheckAddress(addr => $emailaddress,method  => 'extended',timeout => 12,debug   => 0);
print $code;
```

I have a proxy address

Now how to add it to outgoing request for eg i have to use proxy with this function

```
my $code = Mail::VRFY::CheckAddress(addr => $emailaddress,method  => 'extended',timeout => 12,debug   => 0);
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`Mail::VRFY` [uses DNS and SMTP](https://metacpan.org/source/JKISTER/Mail-VRFY-1.01/VRFY.pm) to verify email addresses. I guess that by "proxy address" you mean an HTTP proxy. This kind of proxy server won't help you, since no HTTP connections are involved.

Comment: can i like set proxy to core perl script(I want to run every perl script via proxy(The script which does not even have http connections))